# TFLite c++ determine the classification on output

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to get an output from a trained model which has a classification, the input node count is 1, and the output node count is 2. However, I'm not quite sure where the classification lands and how exactly do I handle it.

```cpp
        for(size_t idx = 0; idx < input_node_count; idx++)
        {
            float* data_ptr = interpreter->typed_input_tensor<float>(idx);
            memcpy(data_ptr, my_input.data(), input_elem_size[idx]);
        }

        if (kTfLiteOk != interpreter->Invoke()) 
        {
            return false;
        }

        for(size_t idx = 0; idx < output_node_count; idx++)
        {
            float* output = interpreter->typed_output_tensor<float>(idx);

            output_buffer[idx] = std::vector<float> (output,
                output + output_elem_size[idx]);
        }

        result = output_buffer[1];
        classification_result = output_buffer[0]; // Best way to approach this
```

As of now, I can just print out the sizes and see that `result` is 196.608 elements and `classification_result` is 2, as it should. My problem is I hard-coded this to be index `1` and `0` but this might not always be the case in my program which runs all sorts of models. So sometimes  classification might be index 1, which causes the above code to fall apart.

I've tried to check the sizes of the buffers however that is also not guaranteed since the classification size and the result size is different for each input. Is there a way for me to know for certain which index is which? Am I approaching this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Use Tensorflow lite signatures for this. Signature defs can help you with that by accessing inputs/outputs using names defined in the original model.

See conversion and inference example [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_python)

Python example

```
# Load the TFLite model in TFLite Interpreter
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(TFLITE_FILE_PATH)
# There is only 1 signature defined in the model,
# so it will return it by default.
# If there are multiple signatures then we can pass the name.
my_signature = interpreter.get_signature_runner()

# my_signature is callable with input as arguments.
output = my_signature(x=tf.constant([1.0], shape=(1,10), dtype=tf.float32))
# 'output' is dictionary with all outputs from the inference.
# In this case we have single output 'result'.
print(output['result'])
```

For C++

```
# To run
auto my_signature = interpreter_->GetSignatureRunner("my_signature");

# Set your inputs and allocate tensors
auto* input_tensor_a = my_signature->input_tensor("input_a");
...

# Execute
my_signature->Invoke();

# output
auto* output_tensor_x = my_signature->output_tensor("output_x");
```